# Assign DataTemplate to view with view model in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I'm trying to set a new DataTemplate as a new Window resource in my MainWindow derived from the System.Windows.Window class. The code for the XAML is quite simple and looks like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
  <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:MyViewModel}">
    <view:MyView />
  </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

What I exactly do here?
I try to show my data (MyViewModel) in or as a specific view (MyView). So far I do understand. Otherwise I wouldn't see the form itself, but the view model as a string with my.namespace.MyViewModel in the window.

But programmatically I do not understand, how to achieve the same. I know, that I have to add a new DataTemplate to the resources of my window. For this I have to "tell" the DataTemplate, which view to use (for the representation) and which data I want to represent, right?

So it must be something with:

```
DataTemplate template = new DataTemplate();
template.DataType = typeof(MyViewModel);

//  Something, something ...

this.Resources.add(...);
```

Is this the right way to go? Or am I completely wrong?
I searched the web for solutions and also my WPF book, but there are only XAML implementations.

Why do I do that?
I have a headered content control which loads view models dynamically. The problem here is, that the user controls are sometimes dynamic and in case of data presentation I need to assign a specific (dynamic created) view to the data. So I try to load the current static user controls also in the way shown above.

Is there a way to go?
Or is there a better way to achieve the same results?

Comment: "*Is this the right way to go?*" - no, it isn't. Better write a DataTemplateSelector and assign it to the ContentTemplateSelector property of a ContentControl or the ItemTemplateSelector property of an ItemsControls. Make the DataTemplateSelector load and return DataTemplates from resources.

Comment: Are you trying to switch data templates for `MyViewModel`?